# Android BLE Scanning: permission denial message in logcat

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I read [Bluetooth LE ScanFilters don't work on Android M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708374/bluetooth-le-scanfilters-dont-work-on-android-m), but it doesnt solve my problem

I am scanning my app on nexus 5 (os: 6.0.1). I keep getting following message in logcat

```
BluetoothUtils: Permission denial: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan
```

Gradle file has following settings:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "XX.XX.XX"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 16
}
```

I am not using API 23 (or above) any where in my gradle but my phone has 6.0.1 OS.

Also, I have following defined in AndroidManifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

I donot ask for runtime permissions as specified in this blog because, I am targeting API 21 
http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/09/29/is-your-beacon-app-ready-for-android-6.html
(when I tried to ask runtime permissions anyway, I get compiler warnings; so I am using GPS instead in the code)

How can I get rid of this warning from logcat

```
Permission denial: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results
```

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37015725/5188159 might help u even if u add permissions on manifest try to prompt it again manually and see

Comment: Earlier, i added the code for permissions from the blog post of the link you referred. But I had compiler issues, bcos my gradle build is targeted towards 21. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Could it be, that you deactivated location in the settings? In order to receive ble scan results you need to have the location active.

Comment: I always get the scan results (at least on Nexus5). However only sometimes, randomly, I get these warnings.