# Bluetooth Scanfilter UUID in android 7.1.1 Not working but works in 6.0.1

Tags: android, filter, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

Have an app that is trying to connect to a Laird Bluetooth BLE chip but when using the `Scanfilter` it cannot be found. In fact I cannot seem to see any bluetooth devices when using a `ScanFilter`.
If I comment out adding the filter `//filters.add(filter);` I can see the devices I wish to connect to and can use them as expected on the 7.1.1 device.

Works on a Nexus 5 with android 6.0.1 with the scanfilter
Does not work on an Asus Zoom 3 7.1.1

I suspect there is some sort of android/os bug at this point but cannot figure out why simply using the filter (that works on an earlier version of android)

Note: App has location permission and bluetooth permissions and requests them in the activity that is scanning for bluetooth

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Code:

```
    ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString("6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"), ParcelUuid.fromString("000000000-1000-0000-0000-000000000000")).build();
    List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
    filters.add(filter);
    ScanSettings scanSettings =
            new ScanSettings.Builder().build();
    bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, scanSettings, mLeScanCallback);
    cancelButton.setText(R.string.cancel);
```

When using the above code it works, on 6.0.1 but not on 7.1.1 I even reduced the mask to a single digit, and can confirm the device UUID in the callback method when debugging and it should be matched.

Asked for permission, even followed 
[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708374/bluetooth-le-scanfilters-dont-work-on-android-m)

But it was just a different way of asking for permissions I had already requested. But tried the methods described here anyways. Still would not list devices using the Scanfilter, but works fine if I remove the `filters.add(filter);` line

Comment: Hi @Charon, did you get any solutions if yes then please provide answer to your own question.

Comment: I seem to recall there being an issue with the scanfilter itself. And there were comments in other areas about it not working properly in some configurations or versions. I ended up not using the built in scan filter and instead filtering the results myself.