# Does BLE connection require ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission in android 10?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-10.0

I have job scheduler which searches BLE devices and connects in background. Android 10 introduced new ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission. Does ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission require to connection BLE device in background?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Location needs to be enabled for Bluetooth Low Energy Scanning on Android 10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220159/location-needs-to-be-enabled-for-bluetooth-low-energy-scanning-on-android-10-0)

Comment: My question is about background ble connection.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#Permissions only mentions the app needs `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, so I suspect you don't need `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`. But I see it likely this will be changed in the near future.

A quick look at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r32/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/GattService.java#1949 shows that only the fine permission seems to be needed, but I can have missed something.

I suggest you to simply try with only `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` to see what happens in the background.

Comment: If you try to scan for a device while in the background it just returns no devices. No errors or warnings. You need to explicitly request ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION then it works

Answer (score 1):

I Think this article would help as it talks about location permission in android 11 and use of BLE.

[Location](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/location/).

also i would recommend you use Foreground services to give your user more insight on what your app is doing and allow them to determine if they need to give you app the permission once, or always.

[Running a service in the foreground](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground)

Answer (score 0):

Android documentation says:

> If your app supports a service and can run on Android 10 (API level 29) or Android 11, you must also declare the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission to discover Bluetooth devices. For more information on this requirement, see [Access location in the background](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background).

More information here: [Android bluetooth permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#discover-local-devices)

So answer is: If you scan for devices or connect to them from service (even foreground service) you need to request for ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission.