# Bluetooth scanner not discovering devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetoothlescanner

I am creating a Bluetooth scanner app and trying to find the available devices to pair. I have a Bluetooth headset which I am trying to find running the application on android 10.

Permissions are set in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

App contains a simple button on whose click I start discovery for bluetooth device

```
val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
val bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
if (bluetoothAdapter == null || !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
    val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
}
val bluetoothLeScanner = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().bluetoothLeScanner
scanBluettoth.setOnClickListener({
    bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(leScanCallback)
})
```

Callback for discovery

```
val leScanCallback: ScanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
    override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)
        Log.e("device ", "D ".plus(result.device.name))
    }
}
```

Can someone help me out if I am missing something here?

Comment: Do you have allowed Location permission?? from Setting

Answer (score 1):

Is location on the device turned off?
Location has to be enabled for Android 10 to get scan results.

Also remember to also ask for permission

```
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
   requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERM);
}
```