# Issue with Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for AttributionSource

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am using a printer d11 and trying to connect it to my device using Bluetooth. But I am encountering this error: Need android. permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for AttributionSource.

I have already added the permissions and all but I'm still having errors, it points me out that the problem is here.

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun searchForPrinters() {
        val bluetoothManager =
            requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            AlertsUtil.showBaseOkWarningDialog(
                requireActivity(),
                getString(R.string.bluetooth_not_available),
                ""
            )
            return
        } else if (!bluetoothAdapter!!.isEnabled) {
            askToEnableBluetooth()
            return
        }

        // The line that causes the problem
        if (bluetoothAdapter?.isDiscovering == true) {
            Logger.log(TAG, "cancel start discovery")
            bluetoothAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()
        }

        initBluetoothScanBroadcastReceiver()
        bluetoothAdapter?.startDiscovery()
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions).

Comment: I edited the post , it's at this part of the code where I am getting the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below permissions on the `Manifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
```

Checking whether permissions are granted by the user

```
private fun isPermissionsGranted(context: Context): Boolean {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    } else {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
}
```

Request user permission to proceed with Bluetooth Scan.

```
if (!isPermissionsGranted(activity)) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        val permissions = mutableSetOf(
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        )

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)
        }

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            activity, permissions.toTypedArray(), 600
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I had these already implemented but it still crashing. It shows me that the issue is on this part
`if (bluetoothAdapter?.isDiscovering == true) {



            Logger.log(TAG, "cancel start discovery")


            bluetoothAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()
        }



        initBluetoothScanBroadcastReceiver()


        bluetoothAdapter?.startDiscovery()`

Comment: You can't check bluetoothAdapter without checking permission

Comment: Request permission on top of private fun searchForPrinters() {

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, I didn't request permissions.

Comment: Welcome please upvote the answer if it's useful

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Bluetooth properly on your Android device, the following permissions need to be added to your manifest file:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
```

Then these permissions should be requested at runtime as can be seen in the links below:-

- [Bluetooth scanner not discovering devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105856/bluetooth-scanner-not-discovering-devices)
- [Turn on LE scanning without asking for user permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65795843/turn-on-android-le-scanning-without-asking-user-for-permission)
- [How to request location permission at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142331/how-to-request-location-permission-at-runtime)
- [The ultimate guide to Android BLE](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)

Comment: Added all of these but still having issues.