# Flutter Android 13 Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

i am getting error when i tried to scan Bluetooth Devices..! its working on Android 10 but when i tried to run on Android 13 i ma getting issue like
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for android.content.AttributionSource@d477eb39: Starting discovery., null, java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for android.content.AttributionSource

i am using flutter_bluetooth_serial: ^0.4.0

Please any one help me out

AndroidManifest file

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<application
    android:label="Hydration Monitor"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
</manifest>
```

here is my code for scan

```
 void _startDiscovery() async {
try {
  FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.startDiscovery().listen((result) async {
// Add data to the list only if it's not a duplicate
  });
} on Exception catch (e) {
  print('Error during discovery: $e');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The permissions BLUETOOTH_SCAN, BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, and BLUETOOTH_CONNECT are runtime permissions therefore in addition to being added to the manifest file, they need to be approved by the user from within the app. You also need to add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to your manifest file for BLE operation. Have a look at the links below for more info:-

- [How to request permissions at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142331/how-to-request-location-permission-at-runtime)
- [Android BLE permissions](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions)
- [Bluetooth scanner not discovering devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105856/bluetooth-scanner-not-discovering-devices)
- [The ultimate guide to Android BLE](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide)