# Turn on Android LE scanning without asking user for permission

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

Some surveys and analytics showed that users very often turn down Location Permission request appearing in the mobile app even if this permission is crucial for the app, e.g. the app performs automatic scan for devices in a venue that handle business logic and exchange data with the mobile app. The permission request turn down rate is so high that it becomes problematic for business. Is there any way in Android to avoid this, e.g. to declare some verified devices that can be scanned without permission request? I thought of https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing but it also means popping up requests for manual work for the user. Is there any way today to do it behind the scenes?

Comment: Beside the already awesome answer you got I would suggest to be very open about what you need the permissions for. You could show an informational text with links for further information before asking for the permission. This could be another question at https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible for privacy and security reasons. Enabling BLE on Android devices goes hand in hand with the location permission. The only possible workaround for this is potentially if you use classic Bluetooth instead of BLE. I am not 100% sure about this one, but it is mentioned in [this article](https://www.polidea.com/blog/a-curious-relationship-android-ble-and-location/):-

> No one can use BLE scan API without having Location Permissions, and,
> on most devices, it is useless without active Location Services.
> However, Bluetooth Low Energy is an extension to so-called Bluetooth
> Classic and interestingly enough Google decided this API does not need
> location permissions to be called.

This is an OS requirement which cannot be overcome. You might've already seen this on the [Android developer page for BLE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth):-

> In order to use Bluetooth features in your application, you must
> declare two permissions. The first of these is BLUETOOTH. You need
> this permission to perform any Bluetooth communication, such as
> requesting a connection, accepting a connection, and transferring
> data.
>
> The other permission that you must declare is ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.
> Your app needs this permission because a Bluetooth scan can be used to
> gather information about the location of the user. This information
> may come from the user's own devices, as well as Bluetooth beacons in
> use at locations such as shops and transit facilities.

You can find more info about this here:-

- [The Ultimate Guide to Android BLE Development](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)
- [Location needs to be enabled for BLE on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220159/location-needs-to-be-enabled-for-bluetooth-low-energy-scanning-on-android-10-0)
- [Bluetooth versus Location Permission](https://support.google.com/android/thread/26338330?hl=en)