# Scan BLE with Kotlin needs permission every time

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an android app using kotlin. When I write some logic about scanning BLE devices, no matter what I wanna do, it needs permission. For example, in this function, I ask for permissions.

```kotlin
private fun startBleScan() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && !isLocationPermissionGranted) {
        requestLocationPermission()
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        requestBleScanPermission()
    }
    bleScanner.startScan(scanFilters, scanSettings, scanCallback)
    }
```

But when I wanna working with stopBleScan, it also needs permissions.(I haven't add yet, now ide tells me to add permissions)

```kotlin
private fun stopBleScan() {
    bleScanner.startScan(scanCallback)
}
```

At last, when I wanna use result.device.name, ide also tells me it needs permission.(Without permission, I can only use result.device, I don't know why).

```kotlin
private val scanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
    override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
        with(result.device) {
            Log.i("ScanCallback", "$name") // ide tells me it needs permission, this line doesn't work
            foundDevice = true
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any solution, so I can only ask permissions for one time, I think it is normal otherwise do it everytime. I'm really new to kotlin and BLE, please help me, Thank you in advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly, and it is the IDE signalling you that the function requires some permission, you can simply add the annotation `@RequiresPermission("android.permission.PERMISSION_NAME")` to the functions, or suppress the warning with `@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to BLE scan for devices on Android, several permissions need to be added to the manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) as follows:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

This is in addition to needing to request permission from the user dynamically. Have a look at the links below for more information:-

- [The ultimate guide to Android BLE development](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)
- [Location needs to be enabled for BLE scanning on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045581/location-needs-to-be-enabled-for-bluetooth-low-energy-scanning-on-android-6-0)
- [Location needs to be enabled for BLE scanning on Android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220159/location-needs-to-be-enabled-for-bluetooth-low-energy-scanning-on-android-10-0/58232014#58232014)
- [Turn on Android LE scanning without asking user permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65795843/turn-on-android-le-scanning-without-asking-user-for-permission)

Comment: Note that with Android 12 as target, you have totally new permissions that must be used instead.

Comment: I already add these permissions.     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />